# How to downsample a Highstock Flag Series

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with several series on it, one of which is a flag series. The data on the flag series is reasonably sparse, but very bursty. As a result when I am showing a large amount of data, ~10 flags tend to line up up next to each other all pointing to basically the same point on the graph.

What I'd like is for those flags to get downsampled (in a sense) so I only show 1 flag indicator that points to the general area where all the flag points are, then when the user zooms in, all the flag points are displayed since it's now possible to actually distinguish what they are pointing at.

This seems like a job for data grouping and when I am zoomed out and showing large data ranges, all my other series end up getting downsampled by data grouping. However, this isn't being applied to the flag series, I suspect because the series doesn't qualify since it has relatively few points across the range being shown.

Does anyone know if there's anything built in that will help me achieve this? Or do I have to write my own downsampling that's tied into the setExtremes event somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you prepare a working example with your chart? It will be easier to work on your specific case.

Comment: I think this example more or less demonstrates what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/flags-allowoverlapx. What I'd like is to just display a single marker for the whole cluster of flags, until the user zooms in.

Comment: Right now, I'm ending up with something like this: https://imgur.com/CpRksHK

Comment: You can use the plugin FLAGS-GROUPING: https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/41/flags-grouping. Demos: http://e.gluhotorenko.com/highcharts-flags-grouping/demo/demo1.html, http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7yk4dxbn/

Comment: That looks perfect, thanks so much.